# How to use mv command to move files from one folder to other folder in python?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to move the files from one folder to other folder using mv and os.sys command. Here is my code
    `x =os.listdir("/home/user/Desktop/previous/")
    for files in x:
    current = "/home/user/Desktop/previous/"
    full_path = current + "/" + files
    os.system ("mv/fullpath/"test_file)`
Where test_file is the name of my destination folder. I have done the same job with shutil command and its working but i want to know how I can use mv command and os.system.

Comment: Do not use `os.system()` for this.  `shutil` or `os` is the right package to use, as you have already discovered.

Comment: But there is some error in above code. When I run programe it says invalid syntax. If I define os.system("mv/home/user/Desktop/previous/files" ./Testing). Can you please specify that?

Comment: `for files in os.listdir(path)  if files endswith(".npy")  os.system(mv ...??)